# JavaFX - passing "fx:controller" using namespace

Tags: java, javafx

I am creating `JavaFX` application using the method used here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javafx-productivity-2345000.html

I have two forms that looks alike but with different behavior, so i have two controllers for the same FXML view,,, i am aware that i can create the controllers manually and do: `FXMLLoader.setController..`,, but that way fields annotated with `@Inject` would not be injected.

i tried passing controller with namespaces,, but that did not work.
what can i do?

**EDIT**: some code

First i have Guest FXML file (it is supposed to add and update guests)

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

     <?import de.jensd.fx.glyphs.fontawesome.FontAwesomeIconView?>
     <?import de.jensd.fx.glyphs.materialdesignicons.MaterialDesignIconView?>
     <?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
     <?import javafx.scene.Cursor?>
     <?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
     <?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
     <?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
     <?import javafx.scene.control.Separator?>
     <?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
     <?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
     <?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
     <?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
     <?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

     <AnchorPane fx:id="pnlMain" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="302.0" prefWidth="337.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.ro.terminal.controller.guest.AddGuestController">
        <children>
           <HBox layoutX="-33.0" layoutY="63.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="80.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="10.0">
              <children>
                 <VBox fx:id="boxDetailsHolder" prefHeight="450.0" prefWidth="390.0" spacing="5.0">
                    <children>
                       <Label prefHeight="19.0" prefWidth="178.0" style="-fx-font-size: 13;" text="%FXML.GUEST_DETAILS" textFill="#626973">

                       </Label>
                       <StackPane prefHeight="35.0">
                          <children>
                             <HBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" prefWidth="614.0">
                                <children>
                                   <ComboBox fx:id="cmbSalutation" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="106.0" minWidth="106.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="106.0" styleClass="combo-box-common">
                                      <HBox.margin>
                                         <Insets />
                                      </HBox.margin>
                                      <padding>
                                         <Insets left="25.0" />
                                      </padding>
                                   </ComboBox>
                                   <TextField fx:id="txtGuestName" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="311.0" promptText="%General.NAME" styleClass="text-field-common">
                                      <HBox.margin>
                                         <Insets left="5.0" right="10.0" />
                                      </HBox.margin>
                                   </TextField>
                                </children>
                             </HBox>
                             <MaterialDesignIconView fill="#6e7175" glyphName="ACCOUNT" size="25" StackPane.alignment="CENTER_LEFT">
                                <StackPane.margin>
                                   <Insets left="5.0" />
                                </StackPane.margin>
                             </MaterialDesignIconView>
                          </children>
                          <VBox.margin>
                             <Insets top="10.0" />
                          </VBox.margin>
                       </StackPane>
                       <StackPane prefHeight="35.0">
                          <children>
                             <HBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="664.0">
                                <children>
                                   <ComboBox fx:id="cmbCountry" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="106.0" minWidth="106.0" prefWidth="106.0" styleClass="combo-box-common">
                                      <HBox.margin>
                                         <Insets />
                                      </HBox.margin>
                                      <padding>
                                         <Insets left="25.0" />
                                      </padding>
                                   </ComboBox>
                                   <StackPane HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                                      <children>
                                         <TextField fx:id="txtPhone" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" prefWidth="153.0" promptText="%General.PHONE_NUM" styleClass="text-field-common">
                                            <padding>
                                               <Insets left="6.0" right="50.0" />
                                            </padding>
                                            <StackPane.margin>
                                               <Insets left="5.0" />
                                            </StackPane.margin>
                                         </TextField>
                                         <Button fx:id="btnDuplicatePhone" mnemonicParsing="false" styleClass="btn-third-level" visible="false" StackPane.alignment="CENTER_RIGHT">
                                            <graphic>
                                               <MaterialDesignIconView glyphName="ACCOUNT_MULTIPLE_OUTLINE" size="20" />
                                            </graphic>
                                            <StackPane.margin>
                                               <Insets right="5.0" />
                                            </StackPane.margin>
                                         </Button>
                                      </children>
                                      <HBox.margin>
                                         <Insets right="10.0" />
                                      </HBox.margin>
                                   </StackPane>
                                </children>
                             </HBox>
                             <MaterialDesignIconView fill="#6e7175" glyphName="CELLPHONE" size="20" StackPane.alignment="CENTER_LEFT">
                                <StackPane.margin>
                                   <Insets left="7.0" />
                                </StackPane.margin>
                             </MaterialDesignIconView>
                          </children>
                       </StackPane>
                       <StackPane prefHeight="35.0">
                          <children>
                             <TextField fx:id="txtEmail" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" prefWidth="264.0" promptText="%General.EMAIL" styleClass="text-field-common">
                                <StackPane.margin>
                                   <Insets right="10.0" />
                                </StackPane.margin>
                                <padding>
                                   <Insets left="35.0" right="50.0" />
                                </padding>
                             </TextField>
                             <MaterialDesignIconView fill="#6e7175" glyphName="EMAIL" size="20" StackPane.alignment="CENTER_LEFT">
                                <StackPane.margin>
                                   <Insets left="7.0" />
                                </StackPane.margin>
                             </MaterialDesignIconView>
                             <Button fx:id="btnDuplicateEmail" mnemonicParsing="false" styleClass="btn-third-level" visible="false" StackPane.alignment="CENTER_RIGHT">
                                <graphic>
                                   <MaterialDesignIconView glyphName="ACCOUNT_MULTIPLE_OUTLINE" size="20" />
                                </graphic>
                                <StackPane.margin>
                                   <Insets right="15.0" />
                                </StackPane.margin>
                             </Button>
                          </children>
                       </StackPane>
                    </children>
                 </VBox>
              </children>
           </HBox>
           <Separator layoutY="558.0" prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="67.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="10.0" />
           <HBox alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" layoutX="711.0" layoutY="558.0" prefHeight="70.0" prefWidth="337.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0">
              <children>
                 <Button fx:id="btnAddGuest" graphicTextGap="5.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="120.0" styleClass="btn-secondary" textFill="#626973">
                    <HBox.margin>
                       <Insets right="20.0" />
                    </HBox.margin>

                    <cursor>
                       <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
                    </cursor>
                    <graphic>
                       <FontAwesomeIconView fill="#626973" glyphName="PLUS" size="15" />
                    </graphic>
                 </Button>
              </children>
           </HBox>
        </children>
     </AnchorPane>
```

AddGuestController :

```
    public class AddGuestController extends AbstractController {
        /**
         * 
         */
        @FXML private AnchorPane pnlMain;
        /**
         * 
         */
        @FXML private TextField txtGuestName, txtEmail, txtPhone;
        @FXML private ComboBox<Country> cmbCountry;
        @FXML private ComboBox<Salutation> cmbSalutation;
        @FXML private Button btnAddGuest;

        @Inject private Guest guest;

        @Override
        public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

            initGuest(); // this will be called on guest add only 
            setGuest(guest); // this will be called on guest update only
            initMainActions();



        }


        /**
         * @param guest
         */
        private void setGuest(Guest guest) {

            this.guest = guest;


            txtGuestName.setText(this.guest.getGuestName());
            txtEmail.setText(this.guest.getEmailAddress());
            txtPhone.setText(this.guest.getPhoneNumber());
            cmbCountry.getSelectionModel().select(this.guest.getCountry());
            cmbSalutation.getSelectionModel().select(this.guest.getSalutation());
        }

        /**
         * 
         */
        private void initMainActions() {
            // use this on adding a guest
            btnAddGuest.setOnAction(e-> {
                if (localValidation()){
                    GuestCommonModel.addGuest(guest);
                }
            });

            // use this on updating a guest
    //      btnAddGuest.setOnAction(e -> {
    //          if (localValidation()){
    //              GuestCommonModel.updateGuest(guest);
    //          }
    //      });
        }
        /**
         * 
         */
        private void initGuest() {
            if (guest != null)
                return;

            guest = new Guest();

            guest.setPersonId(IDUtils.newID());
            guest.setContactId(IDUtils.newID());
            guest.setCityId(TerminalModule.instance().getVenue().getCityId());
            guest.setAcceptEmail(true);
            guest.setAcceptSms(true);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Why don't just create 1 controller for your view and pass the reference of that controller to your 2nd controller?

Comment: @THe_strOX would not that look really bad? trying to keep the code clean

Comment: One option might be to wrap a common FXML file (with a single controller that has the common functionality) in two other FXML files using `<fx:include>`. Each of the other FXML files would have their own controllers which could reference the common controller (via [nested controllers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#nested_controllers)) and define the specific functionality for that particular use. The controller factory is propagated to FXMLs loaded via `<fx:include>`, so the afterburner.fx machinery will work on the included FXMLs.

Comment: Your question would probably be easier to answer definitively if you posted an example showing the problem you are trying to solve...

Comment: Perhaps a better way is to provide an `injectionContext` when you create the view. This would genuinely allow you to use a single FXML and a single controller, but the `injectionContext` allows you to control the actual creation of objects supplied to `@Inject`-annotated fields. Again, I would need an example to see if this worked.

Comment: @James_D thank you very much,,, the code is kinda huge,, i simplified it so the idea can be understood (check the edit).

Comment: @James_D <fx:include> is a good solution but i was hoping to pass the controller somehow